# Process Explorer: How to find out what System PID 4 is

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Using Process Explorer I can see that a certain file is locked by "System, PID: 4". This blocks the VB.NET VS2012 IDE from recreating the file. I am getting the "Permission denied" error. It always takes a few minutes until the file is released.

I have tried to disable just anything that might lock my file... Application compatibility, Backups, Windows Defender, Windows Indexer, just anything I could think of.

How could I find out which application "System, PID: 4" really is?

Thank you.

I know that my question sounds very much like this one:
[How do I find out any more information about file handles held open by the System process?](https://superuser.com/questions/373625/how-do-i-find-out-any-more-information-about-file-handles-held-open-by-the-syste)

But in my case I do not have a network, so that can not be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Make sure the **Application Experience Lookup Service** (`AeLookupSvc`) is not disabled. By default, it should be set to **Manual**.

Comment: related https://superuser.com/questions/1395899/when-system-pid-4-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-how-can-i-determine-what-program/1517801#1517801  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685916/unable-to-copy-file-obj-debug-to-bin-debug-access-to-the-path-bin-debug-is-deni/53334130#53334130 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378192/windows-2008-r2-kernel-system-process-pid-4-is-locking-files-and-folders  Particularly the second link.

Comment: @and31415 yeah and for me a a bug in MBAM(malware bytes), was causing it to say "stopping". Not sure if a restart worked, as I had lots of unsaved notepad windows open. I didn't rush to do that.. I did uninstall malware bytes.  and maybe restarted, and that fixed it

Answer (score 4):

It's the Windows Kernel. This virtual process contains all running kernel-mode drivers. This also includes Windows File Sharing, HTTP.SYS and probably all virus scanners.

Unfortunately, file handle accounting is only done at process level, so you won't be able to get additional information.